# wamp server \ apache on Windows 7 does not load css and js files in subfolders

Tags: php, css, apache, windows-7, wampserver

I've tried several versions of WAMP: 2.0 2.2 2.4 2.5 32 and 64, 
and I've tried Apache stand alone on WINDOWS 7.

Root pages load but css, js and any other included files in sub-folders within a site do not load and Apace logs an access denied error.
It happens if the site is in the wamp/www folder or is an Apace alias.

I've tried gone through each step of the documentation, tried every config setting, install option, folder permissions, every idea found here and in every blog post Google returns in the search and nothing has worked. Allow all, vhosts, all those suggestions have failed.

What is up with WAMP/Apache on Windows 7? It worked fine right out of the box on my old XP machine.

thanks everyone hope someone has found a fix...
best, omcode

Comment: this belongs on serverfault.

Comment: access denied is either something at the apache level is denying access, or something at the filesystem level is preventing apache from getting into those files/dirs. but since you haven't provided any actual config details, we can't really help you.

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried so many different config settings I'm not sure what to share here. I can't paste it all in, but the last attempt using Apache was:  

# DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "F:\Sites"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
...
# <Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/htdocs">
<Directory "F:\Sites">
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: Could we start by you showing a sample of the HTML code that you say does not load the required css or js. Also include the folder structure you are using. NOTE: Its better to install into a `c:\wamp` or `d:\wamp` or any drive, but the root folder and without any spaces in the folder names.

Comment: Here's some of the HTML, have variety a varied of paths, and when viewed as a file everything loads and the exact same code works and servers properly from an old XP machine running WAMP but same install and HTML code does not work on Windows 7.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation/css/foundation.css">
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <h1>Welcome to Foundation</h1>
    <ul class="tabs" data-tab>
      <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panel2-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-3">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into the source of the page (in your Browser), you'll quickly see that all your linked assets are using bad, non-resolving, or the wrong: path, domain, host, IP.

Answer (score 0):

Possible walk trough's

1. check if rewrite_module is loaded if not check it and restart wamp.
2. Avoid relative path use absolute.
3. Check if the path & file-name is correct.

One of these will definitely be helpful for you.